# .charAt and .toLowerCase Conundrum

Tags: javascript

need a bit of help please.
I need to make the response from yesOrNo .toLowerCase() and .charAt(0) also check the responce is == to 'y'.
any help appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>'Schittys Pizza'</title>
<script>
// Asks if you want to order
var yesOrNo = prompt('Welcome to Schitty\'s pizza, would you like to order?, Yes or         No?');
    if(yesOrNo == 'y') {
    // Asks Address
    var address = prompt('What is your Address?')
    while (address == null || address == '')
    address = prompt('What is your address, please?')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call a function on a variable?

Comment: `yesOrNo.toLowerCase().charAt(0)`. You're welcome.

Comment: I like it how you use _please_ only on the second and successive calls

Comment: Or `yesOrNo.charAt(0).toLowerCase()`, which is more efficient than @FelixKling's version

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var yesOrNo = prompt('Welcome to Schitty\'s pizza, would you like to order?, Yes or No?').toLowerCase()[0];

if(yesOrNo === 'y') {
    // do your yes logic
}
```

or

```
var yesOrNo = prompt('Welcome to Schitty\'s pizza, would you like to order?, Yes or No?').toLowerCase();

if(yesOrNo[0] === 'y') {
    // do your yes logic
}
```

or

```
var yesOrNo = prompt('Welcome to Schitty\'s pizza, would you like to order?, Yes or No?');

if(yesOrNo.toLowerCase()[0] === 'y') {
    // do your yes logic
}
```

or

```
var yesOrNo = prompt('Welcome to Schitty\'s pizza, would you like to order?, Yes or No?');

if(yesOrNo.toLowerCase().charAt(0) === 'y') {
    // do your yes logic
}
```

Comment: What if my answer was "Yeah, nah"

Comment: @JK :) since there is a check for first char it will consider it as Yes.